# Is there a way when creating new SVN repositories for the client (tortoisesvn) to create the branches, tags and trunk folders automaticlly?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm using tortoisesvn to create the repositories and wondered if there was a way it could automatically create a skeleton directory structure within the repository?

I need this as I'm going to allow other people in the team to set-up new repositories and I need to make it as simple as possible and minimise mistakes. I would like the tags, branches and trunk directories to be created automatically.

Comment: If they are setting up new repositories using TortoiseSVN, they're just using their own repository locally? Why?

Comment: They are not actually. The repositories are on a Linux server. I have setup a samba share to the repositories folder which can be accessed via windows. Setting up new repositories is as simple as created a new folder and then right-clicking and selecting Create Repository here... menu option provided by TortoiseSVN. 

This means that you don't need to login to the Linux server via SSH to setup a new site/repository which I would not want to give the other members of the team access to.

Also FYI the repositories are backed up daily.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Do you always have a 1-to-1 mapping between repository and project? I'm working with multiple repositories - which all have multiple project folders in them with their own tags, branches and trunk directories.

Comment: Yeah I have one repository for each website. This is because I need a post-commit hook for each project. The post-commit hook updates a working copy of that project and has to have the path of the working copy in the hook file. Unfortunately you can only have one post-commit hook per repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script (in the language of your choice) that creates the repository and commits the predefined directory structure, using the `svn` command line client.

Answer (score 1):

Make a script. If you are on Windows, a bat. On Linux etc, an bash.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. create an empty repository
2. check out a working copy of that empty repository
3. add trunk/branches/tags folders
4. set properties on those folders (e.g., if you're using TSVN you might want to set the tsvn:minlogsize and/or the tsvn:autoprops properties)
5. commit those folders
6. run `svnadmin dump path/to/Repo > templaterepo.dmp`

Now you have a template repository with some settings and folders pre-set.

All you need now is a script which does:

1. svnadmin create path/to/new/Repo
2. svnadmin load --ignore-uuid path/to/new/repo < templaterepo.dmp

and you're done.
But don't forget to pass the `--ignore-uuid` param to `svnadmin load`! Otherwise you'll end up with all your repositories having the same uuid - and **that will cause problems**!

Answer (score 0):

As this is just a convention for organizing a Subversion repository and you don't actually want them at the top level all the time I doubt there is a way to do that automatically on repository creation. Usually you don't create multiple repositories per hour or so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I automatically create a `branches` folder (assuming `trunk` already exists) so I can automatically branch. This is written in C# and uses the SharpSVN dll to do the work. Then it calls TortoiseSVN (not shown) to do the branch.

```
using SharpSvn;

SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
Uri trunkUri = client.GetUriFromWorkingCopy(trunkPath);
if (trunkUri.Segments.Last() != "trunk/")
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Will skip {0}, because first trunk path does not end in \"trunk\\\"",trunkPath));
    return;
} else {
    System.UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(trunkUri);
    builder.Path += "../branches/";
    Uri    parent = builder.Uri;

    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SvnInfoEventArgs> info;
    bool result = client.GetInfo(SvnTarget.FromUri(parent), new SvnInfoArgs { ThrowOnError = false }, out info);
    if (result == false)
    {

       SvnCreateDirectoryArgs args = new SvnCreateDirectoryArgs();
       args.CreateParents = true;
       args.ThrowOnError = true;
       args.LogMessage = String.Format("Creating new branch \"{0}\"", branchName);
       client.RemoteCreateDirectory(parent, args);
    }
    builder.Path += branchName;
    Uri newUrl = builder.Uri;
    TortoiseSVN.Copy(trunkPath, newUrl.ToString(), comment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update for TortoiseSVN 1.7

When you create repository now, after creating you have window with two post-create choices

- Create folder structure
- Run repo-browser

First point is answer on question

[image: Repo-creation dialogue]