# TortoiseSVN create repository with capitalized folder structure (Trunk vs. trunk, etc.)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN has a feature now (not sure when it was introduced) where you can create the trunk/branches/tags folder structure when creating a repository (see @Lazy Badger's answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085484/is-there-a-way-when-creating-new-svn-repositories-for-the-client-tortoisesvn-t)).  However, it creates the folders with lowercase names ("trunk", "branches", and "tags") and my convention has always been to use capitalized names ("Trunk", "Branches", and "Tags").

Is there a setting or config entry somewhere that can be adjusted for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. There's no setting for this.